# Report generated values for Appointment change using sql query

Tags: sql, db2

1. PPLUS has 2 tables for the appointments. APPT for appointment record and APPTLOB for the Appointment lines.
2. Currently, this reports prints a record only when Appointment is change but ignores when a new business line is added or any existing line is updated.
3. If an appointment record got added, deleted and added again on a single day then this report captures only one add and one delete. A change is needed to capture all the activities

I use below sql query earlier:

```
db2 "
SELECT DISTINCT
  SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY, 1, 10) AS PRODUCER_TAX_ID,
  CASE
    WHEN B.SEX_CODE = 'E' THEN TRIM(B.CORPORATE_NAME)
    ELSE TRIM(B.FIRST_NAME) || TRIM(B.MIDDLE_NAME) || TRIM(B.LAST_NAME)
  END AS PRODUCER_NAME,
  SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY, 11, 2) AS STATE_CODE,
  C.APPT_LOB_EFF_DT AS APPOINTMENT_EFFECTIVE_DATE,
  A.ORIGINATOR_CD AS USER_ID,
  CASE
    A.FILE_MAINT_TRX_CD
    WHEN 'LARA' THEN 'ADD'
    WHEN 'LARC' THEN 'UPDATE'
    WHEN 'LARD' THEN 'DELETE'
  END AS TRANSACTION_TYPE,
  C.ELECTRONIC_PROC_IND AS SEND_TO_STATE,
  A.LOG_DT_R AS LAST_CHANGED_DT,
  D.LOB_CD AS LOB_CODE,
  D.APPT_LOB_EFF_DT AS LOB_EFFECTIVE_DATE,
  D.LOG_DT_R AS LOB_LAST_CHANGED_DT
FROM
  "$ENV_SCHEMA".REG_HIST A,
  "$ENV_SCHEMA".MPR B,
  "$ENV_SCHEMA".APPT C,
  "$ENV_SCHEMA".APPTLOB D
WHERE
  A.FILE_MAINT_TRX_CD IN ('LARA', 'LARC', 'LARD')
  AND B.MSTR_AGENT_ID = C.MSTR_AGENT_ID
  AND B.MSTR_AGENT_ID = SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY, 1, 10)
  AND C.MSTR_AGENT_ID = SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY, 1, 10)
  AND C.STATE_CODE = SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY, 11, 2)
  AND D.APPT_ID = C.APPT_ID
ORDER BY
  SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY, 11, 2)
" > "$REPORTAP"
```